# Impossible to answer y-or-n-p prompt in EXWM if X window is focussed

Tags: debugging, prompt, exwm, inputs

When a `y-or-n-p` question (e.g. `The file you want to open is very large. Really want to open it?`) pops up in the minibuffer while an EXWM buffer is focussed, I have no option to answer the question (using `y` or `n`).

In that situation, ALL inputs are forwarded to the buffer's X window, including key bindings I use for EXWM (for example `s-q` to close the current window/buffer or `s-w` to change the active window).

In order to rescue the situation, I have to close the active window (if it's got a menu to do so, as I can't use my exwm hotkeys), which allows me to answer the question (in case the subsequently focussed window is an Emacs (text) buffer).

I have no clue how/why inputs are handled in a different way during this (`y-or-n-p`) question (probably because it's blocking the Emacs event queue which is required for handling X commands?).

How can I debug/fix this issue?

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me. You might want to consider sending a report for it.

Comment: @Drew thanks for the correction. reported now: https://github.com/ch11ng/exwm/issues/611